# EditText hint shifting up

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint, android-textinputlayout

I have an `EditText` field and I've implemented the `TextInputLayoutWidget` to it:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_email"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10">

            <EditText
                style="@style/EditText"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:hint="Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

So, initially, when out of focus, the field looks like this:
[image]

As soon as it gains focus, it changes to this:
[image]

I want this hint-shifting-up to happen after the text change event. Not on gaining focus. How can I achieve that?

Comment: i think it is the default behavior and we cant change it....

Comment: there could be a way of overriding the default behavior? I was just looking for what method causes this shifting-up.

Comment: If you are using the latest design libraries, check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintAnimationEnabled(boolean) .